# How to call custom validation before each method execution in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-aop

I am creating a spring web application with jdk 8, My requirement is

I want to anotate each rest exposed method with `@isValid("bla-bla-bla")` 
now I want to write a common utility method which will validate the Httprequest came to this method against `"bla-bla-bla"`passed in annotation and on failure should return HTTP 403

I know i can do this using Aspect, I wanted to know is there a better way to achieve the same .

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think `RequestBodyAdvice` will solve your requirement.

Comment: Thanks I will check, but this is also Aspect right?

Comment: No. Read about it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestBodyAdvice.html)

Comment: It's still an Aspect, but provided by Spring. I don't see a better way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your custom annotation like this (This scenario may not fit you, but I think the logic is the same.);

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, 
ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { MyValidator.class })
public @interface MyValidationAnnotation {

/**
 * @return
 */
String message() default "Your value is not valid";

/**
 * @return
 */
Class<?>[] groups() default {};

/**
 * @return
 */
Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
```

}

```
public class MyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyValidationAnnotation, String> {
public void initialize(MyValidationAnnotation constraintAnnotation) {
}

public boolean isValid(String id, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    //write your logic here..
    return true;
}
```

}

And finally use @MyValidationAnnotation where you need it.

Comment: Thanks this gives me another clean solution which I was not aware of , but I will go with HandlerInterceptor because of some other requirement.. thanks

Comment: I have annotated my api, annotation validation function is not called, do I need to do anything else ?